# Overlapping marginal histograms using ggExtra in the same chunk

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to create a scatterplot with marginal histograms using a for-loop. Below is my Rmarkdown file and output. The output supposed to show three different scatterplots but it only shows one. I believe they are put on top of each other when they are in the same chunk.

I don't want to create chunks in a loop. How can I create three scatterplots using a loop?

````
---
title: "My Report"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(ggExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

## In for-loop

```{r}
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
  print(ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram"))
}
```


## No for-loop

```{r}
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")


df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")
```


## Separate Chunks 

```{r}
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")

```

```{r}
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")
```
````

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Solved using the comment [here](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/147#issuecomment-519350970).

When printing a `ggmarginal` object, use `print(p, newpage = TRUE)` instead of `print(p)`.

````
```{r}
for (i in 1:3) {
  df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
  print(ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram"), newpage = TRUE)
}
```
````